# Is it helpful to get credit for an independent study project?

Tags: graduate-admissions, transcript-of-records, independent-study

Suppose a college senior has made arrangements to do an independent study project with a professor, in order to learn more about a particular topic, with guidance.  When it comes to the graduate admissions scrutiny of the transcript, are there any advantages to getting credit for the independent study, as opposed to keeping things informal?  Note that an independent study course would not count toward the gpa.

If you want more context, see [this question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/83939/32436).